# Layout not updating when run on device after change xml android studio

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-studio

When I change xml layout code and run on device, it is not updated but If I clean project, it will be updated.

Any body can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: it sometimes happen really..

Comment: facing the same issue, how did you fix it? :)

Answer (score 1):

if  you create multiple layout with same name and store in different folder(Layout-large, Layout-normal.... etc) then u have change in all layout file.